# How to get the value of the span element with testid using react testing library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I want to get the value of the span element using react testing library.

What i am trying to do?

I have a span element like below displaying some value

```
render = () => {
    const count = 2;
    return (
        <span data-test-id="test-span">
            {count}
        </span>
     )
 }
```

Now within my test i access the element like below,

```
const span_element = getByTestId('test-span');
```

But i am not sure how to retrieve its value.

I tried using span_element.value but says 'property value doesnt exist on HTMLElement"

How can i fix this. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: The right syntax is "data-testid" and not "data-test-id"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you need is the text content of the DOM element :

```
const spanTextContent: string = getByTestId('test-span').textContent;
```

See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Note that `textContent` will return the text content of the node **and all its descendants**.

`value` usually refers to the value attribute of interactive elements like inputs, and you could retrieve it like so :

```
const inputValue: string = getByTestId('refers-to-input').getAttribute('value');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/number#value

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach:

***Component.js***

```
...
render = () => {
    const count = 2;
    return (
        <span id="test-span">
            {count}
        </span>
     )
 }
...
```

***Component.test.js***

```
import { screen } from "@testing-library/react";
...
// get HTML DOM element
const spanElement = await screen.queryByTestId('test-span');
// OR
// const spanElement = await screen.querySelector('test-span');

// get value from HTML DOM element
const spanElementValue = spanElement.getAttribute('value');
...
```